# Updating a value on a ArrayList which feeds a ListView is not displaying the new value

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist

I have a **ListView of comments**, think of it like a **sort of Twitter**. So each comment has a button and a count, **like a retweet button and a TextView that shows the number of retweets**. When the button is clicked I execute an AsyncTask that updates the value on the online DB and when it gets back it **updates the value in the ArrayList**. Finally I call `notifyDataSetChanged()` and also call `myTextView.SetText(//new number)` **but the new value is never shown and the old one stays on the UI**.
I skipped the code that doesnt take part in this action.

This is the setOnClickListener called from the adapter:

```
agreeB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
             FetchCommentToUpVote upVote = new FetchCommentToUpVote();
             upVote.execute(getItem(position).getId());
        }
```

}

This is how I update the local value of the ArrayList and how I try to display it:

```
@Override
protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {                 
     CommentsFragment.lista.set(mPosition, commentFetched);
}

@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer pos){

        num_agree.setText(Integer.toString(CommentsFragment.lista.get(pos).getAgree()));

        notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

I have checked and the value in the ArrayList is certainly changed but never displayed.
Thanks in advanced!

Comment: @g2o its 200 lines long... :S thats why only put the code taking part in this action and TextView

Comment: Ok i just need it to check if your CommentsFragment.lista, btw i supose that you speak Spanish...so i write you this in spanish :)...muchos problemas parecidos son porque la lista que tienes en CommentsFragment.lista no esta sincronizada con la lista del adapter :)

Comment: Puede ser que sea eso dado que en el Fragment incializo el adaptador una unica vez en el onCreateView. ¿Como puedo hacer que este constantemente sincronizada?

Comment: Voy a ponerlo como respuesta ;) en ingles...

Comment: What is `num_agree`?

Comment: Why is `lista` a static member of `CommentsFragment`? This seems like a poor design choice.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice so I can access it from the adapter

Answer (score 0):

Check that your `CommentsFragment.lista` and your array adapter variable are syncronized.

Edit: Create a method setArrayItems in your adapter and call this when your `CommentsFragment.lista` is updated.

Hope it helps!!

Comment: Sorry but I dont really get what the setArrayItems method should do since the adapter is not the one that has the items...

Comment: can you extend your answer a little bit please?